# Angular 2 Materials Md-tab w/ routing issues

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing

I am trying to create a tab-based dashboard in angular 2 and love material design's md-tab component, but am having trouble keeping persistent routes defined in the tab content groups. The code I pasted is just my mock up but ideally it would be great if I could have one  to worry about and just have each tab route to different links, but I cant seem to find a working solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
</md-toolbar>
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>One</template>
    <template md-tab-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </template>
    <nav>
    <!--a routerLink="/dashboards" routerLinkActive="active">One</a-->
  </nav>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>Two</template>
    <template md-tab-content>
      <h1>HELLO</h1>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </template>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>Three</template>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>Four</template>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab>
    <template md-tab-label>Five</template>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Comment: Provide more details on what your tried and what error/issue you are getting?

Comment: There is no error, the tabs just dont reload the route if i click a different tab. So if Tab 1 loads some dynamic route, and then i click tab 2 which displays "HELLO", then when i click tab 1 again nothing appears.

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? If you did, would you mind posting the answer?